# replace funcion only first occurence

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have this code

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.replace('\r\n', ':'));
});
```

replace line breaks with ":"

Is working, but only for the first occurrence.

How can I do it to replace for all occurrences?
Thank you so much

Comment: What does data look like

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
var str = "This is sample text for a sample replace";  
str = str.replace(/sample/g, "lovely");
console.log(str);

//string replace n times 
let logLine ="This is sample text sample for a sample replace sample";  
var N = 2;
while(--N + 1){
  logLine = logLine.replace('sample', "lovely");
}
console.log(logLine);
```

Comment: Thank you! is working perfectly, but.. how I can make a secuence of replace? for example replace 1 time, 2, and 3 replace and line break "\n" How I can do this?

Comment: @Monikhe  sequence of replacing updated in the answer but I can get meaning of 'line break "\n"'

Comment: @Monikhe mark as answered if it is useful